# Every Hermitian scalar product in $V $ defines on $M=V /\Lambda$ a translation-invariant Kähler metric

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, kahler-manifolds, abelian-varieties

I was reading the chapter on complex tori of Griffith Harris book "principles of Algebraic Geometry" and i read that every Hermitian scalar product on $V $ defines on the torus $M=\mathbb{C^n} /\Lambda$ a translation-invariant Kähler metric. He justify the statement saying that there is a natural isomorphism with $T_\mu'(M) \equiv V$ for every $\mu \in M$. I don't understand how is the metric induced by $V$ and why it is Kahler and traslation-invariant. Could you give me a precise explanation of that?

Comment: Welcome to (posting at) Math.SE! <> Are you happy with the idea that $TV$, the tangent bundle of $V$ (with $V$ viewed as a holomorphic manifold) acquires a metric from an Hermitian structure on $V$ by (canonically) identitying $T_vV \simeq V$ for each $v$ in $V$)? If so, does it make sense that this metric is translation-invariant and Kähler?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang is it trivial that this is a Kahler metric? Probably i'm not confortable with the statement "every Hermitian scalar product defines a Kahler metric" (probably this is trivial but i don't see why).

Comment: The metric coefficients are constant. :)